# How can I execute single .java file with autohotkey?

Tags: cmd, automation, autohotkey

I want to execute selected java code with AutoHotkey.Normally I can execute single java file with following cmd commands:

```
javac execute.java //compiling and creating execute.class
java execute       //executing .class file
```

I want to automate this process with AutoHotkey.I wrote following AutoHotkey code

```
^+e::
sleep 30
Send ^c
sleep 30
FileAppend,Clipboard,"C:\Users\q\Desktop\execute.java"
sleep 30
run cmd.exe,javac execute.java,hide  ; compiling successfully
sleep 2000
results := ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell").Exec("cmd.exe java execute").StdOut.ReadAll() ; can't display executing result
sleep 1000
msgbox % results
return
```

But I get following results:https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMfvl.jpg[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAcAd.png).So I cannot see results properly with  `results := ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell").Exec("cmd.exe java execute").StdOut.ReadAll()` command.How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to read stderr ?

Comment: Thanks.Is there any documentation for "read stderr ".t I don't know how can I use this function.I do some search on google and I can't find any practical demonstration of this function.

Comment: `results := ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell").Exec("cmd.exe java execute").StdDerr.Read() ; `I tried this but it throw unknown name error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues with your script are:

1. You don't need so many `Sleep`'s.
2. Some parameters are in the wrong form.
3. You need a loop to read output from `WScript.Shell`.
4. There are some working directory issues.

The following's been tested to work:

```
^+e::
Java_CopyCompileAndRun() {
    Static objShell := ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell")   ; Speeds up subsequent runs
    KeyWait Shift   ; Possilby unnecessary
    KeyWait e       ; Possilby unnecessary
    Clipboard := ""
    Send ^c
    ClipWait 1
    FileDelete % "C:\Users\q\Desktop\execute.java"
    FileAppend % Clipboard, % "C:\Users\q\Desktop\execute.java"
    RunWait % A_ComSpec " /c ""javac execute.java""", C:\Users\q\Desktop\, Hide
    objExec := objShell.Exec(A_ComSpec " /c ""cd ""C:\Users\q\Desktop\"" & java execute""")
    While !(objExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream && objExec.StdErr.AtEndOfStream) {
        sStdOut   .= objExec.StdOut.ReadAll()
        , sStdErr .= objExec.StdErr.ReadAll()
        Sleep 10
    }
    MsgBox % "StdOut :`n" sStdOut "`n`nStdErr :`n" sStdErr
}
```